# Creating Abaqus Set in Python

Tags: python, abaqus

I would like to create a geometrical set with edges in Abaqus, using Python. I won't know in advance the number of edges. Trying to put the edges in an array and then creating the Set.

```
myEdgesForSet = []

for i in range(0, len(mdb.models['Model'].parts['Part'].edges)):
    if 'something' in mdb.models['Model'].parts['Part'].edges[i].featureName:
        myEdgesForSet.append(mdb.models['Model'].parts['Part'].edges[i])     

mdb.models['Model'].parts['Part'].Set(edges=myEdgesForSet, name='Set')
```

So this code dosen't work, and I can't understand why. Even if I try the following it won't work:

```
mdb.models['Model'].parts['Part'].Set(edges=myEdgesForSet[0], name='Set')
```

So I tried a different approach:

```
myEdgesForSet = []

for i in range(0, len(mdb.models['Model'].parts['Part'].edges)):
    if 'something' in mdb.models['Model'].parts['Part'].edges[i].featureName:
        myEdgesForSet.append(mdb.models['Model'].parts['Part'].edges[i].pointOn[0])     

mdb.models['Model'].parts['Part'].Set(edges=mdb.models['Model'].parts['Part'].edges.findAt((myEdgesForSet, )), name='Set')
```

Which dosen't work, but this works:

```
mdb.models['Model'].parts['Part'].Set(edges=mdb.models['Model'].parts['Part'].edges.findAt((myEdgesForSet[0], )), name='Set')
```

Would really like some advice on how I can make a Set with an unknown number of features.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you get an error message when trying to create a set or is simply nothing happening?

Comment: I get this message: Feature creation failed.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue. If someone else has the same problem:

```
myEdgesForSet = []

for i in range(0, len(mdb.models['Model'].parts['Part'].edges)):
    if 'something' in mdb.models['Model'].parts['Part'].edges[i].featureName:
        myEdgesForSet.append(mdb.models['Model'].parts['Part'].edges[i:i+1])     

mdb.models['Model'].parts['Part'].Set(edges=myEdgesForSet, name='Set')
```